# Validate array fields in a form with Codeigniter 2

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I´m looking to find a nice solution for checking a form field which is submitted as array. The key of the field is already set, so it seems declaring the fieldname as suggested in the manual does not work.

**Here is the example (HTML Code):**

```
<select name="image_status[366]" id="image_status[366]" class="form-control">
<option value="1">Status 1</option>
<option value="2">Status 2</option>
<option value="3">Status 3</option>
<option value="4" selected="selected">Status 4</option>
</select>
```

The key of the element (here it´s 366) is created dynamically and is a database key. Now, if I add the following validation rule, **it´s not checked by Codeigniter**:

```
array(
            'field' => 'image_status[]',
            'label' => 'Status',
            'rules' => 'required'
        )
```

If I use the following rule (which will not work unless I create this rules dynamically which is quite ugly), **the validation works**:

```
array(
            'field' => 'image_status[366]',
            'label' => 'Status',
            'rules' => 'required'
        )
```

Has anybody an idea, how I can define the validation rules, so that it works for an array with a defined index / key?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Michael

Comment: `'field' => 'image_status'` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

make it as a for loop if you are getting selection lists dynamically. do code like following this will create validation dynamically

```
foreach ($selection_list as $key) {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($key."[]" ,$key, "required");
             } 
        }
```